# How to tell bison to generate a parser.cpp and parser.h file instead of parser.cpp and parser.hpp?

Tags: bison

I am using following command

`bison.exe -v -d -l -pTPZyy -bTpz -o %ParserDir%\parser.cpp %ParserDir%\parser.y`

It out puts 'Parser.cpp' and 'Parser.hpp'. In our company we do not have convention of `cpp/hpp` its `cpp/h` files. How can I tell bison to generate a `parser.h` and a `parser.cpp` file?

It tired its documentation but did not find anything about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works on recent versions of bison, although I've never tried it on Windows:

```
bison -v --defines=parser.h --output=parser.cpp parser.y
```

By the way, why are you setting the file prefix (`-b`)? As far as I know, that's only effective if you don't specify an explicit output file. For the `-v` file, you can specify an explicit filename with `--report-file=PATH`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way, we put this in our makefile to do it:

```
    SomeLang.cpp: SomeLang.yy
        $(BISON) $(YACCFLAGS) -osSomeLang.cpp $< && \
        mv SomeLang.hpp SomeLang.h
```